# How can I have access to each building in building layer of google earth?

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I am thinking about making an application that discriminates between buildings based on some attributes using google earth's API.let's say highlighting those with a specific architecture style. the problem is that I don't know how to access each building in the building layer.some say it is not possible.is that true? 
as an alternative solution I tried to import 3D model of each building from 3D warehouse. now I need to be able to highlight them and make them clickable. could you tell me how is that possible?

Answer (score 4):

Right now, it doesn't appear that there is a way to publicly access the building footprint data that's used by Google Maps. There are some alternatives, as discussed in StackExchange GIS: "[Where can I find building footprint data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2046/where-can-i-find-building-footprint-data)".

You should be able to access these through the [OpenStreetMap building outline dataset](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:building=entrance).